# How do I get a input value on ExtJS 6.0

Tags: javascript, extjs

I wonder how do I get the input value from the form in ExtJS.
I have tried several ways "see comments", but none of them gave me a value, i get an error mostly - "undefined".

Another thing that is unclear is where is form name defined ?

Here's my code:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    title: 'Convert Roman characters to Arabic',
    height: 150,
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Enter Roman Character',
            name: 'char'
        }
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function() {
            //var form = formPanel.getForm();
            //var value = form.findField('char');
            //var form = this.up('form'); // get the form panel
            //var value = Ext.getCmp('char').getValue();
            //  var field = Ext.getCmp('char');
                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', "value");

            }
        }
    ]
});
});
```

In the end the application should alert the inputed value.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        text: 'Submit',
        handler: function(btn) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Success',btn.up('form').down('[name=char]').getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //var form = formPanel.getForm();
        //var value = form.findField('char');
        //var form = this.up('form'); // get the form panel
        //var value = Ext.getCmp('char').getValue();
        //  var field = Ext.getCmp('char');
There are multi ways to get value of char field. 

1) To get value like this as you used, you have to give id property for this field :
    {
        fieldLabel: 'Enter Roman Character',
        name: 'char',
        id : 'char' // or give any name
    }
 now used below code to get value  
 var field = Ext.getCmp('char');
 var value = field.getValue();

2) You can also use itemId property same :
    {
        fieldLabel: 'Enter Roman Character',
        name: 'char',
        itemId : 'char' // or give any name
    }
 now used below code to get value  
 var field = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#char')[0];
 var value = field.getValue();

3) another way, you can get value from form values;
  var form = this.up('form'),
  formValues = form.getForm().getValues();
  charValue = formValues.char;
```